# MomentJS startOf('day') seem to be 12 AM (12 in 24-hour format)?

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I have a date stored in YYYY-MM-DD. This date is used to create a moment called `then`. I want to count days between this date and `now` (moment).

When counting days I use: `now.startOf('day').from(then.startOf('day'))`. 
As an example, when testing using two dates with 3 days apart, it will be 3 days until 12 AM (12 in 24-hours format).

Do you guys know any idea why?

Comment: I just run `moment('2014-01-01').format('HH:mm:ss')` it returns `00:00:00` like I expect.

Answer (score 6):

Just wanted to update this.

The beware the difference between HH and hh.

HH is 24 hours so the start of day is 12 where as HH the start is 0.

.format('HH:mm:ss') returns 00:00:00
.format('hh:mm:ss') returns 12:00:00

Comment: Such a small change, but change the whole format. Thanks

Comment: @Justin this line `HH is 24 hours so the start of day is 12 where as HH the start is 0.` seems confusing but i get your point, and yes HH does fix it for me too.

Answer (score 1):

See (moment docs)[[http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/]](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/%5d).

Your example:

```
var moment = require('moment'); 
var a = moment("2014-05-02");
var b = moment();
var whole = a.diff(b, 'days');
var fract = a.diff(b, 'days', true);
console.log("Difference is " + whole + ", or more precisely, " + fract );
```

Returns:

`Difference is 1, or more precisely, 1.404142025462963`